# Regex expressions

Tags: java, regex, mongodb

What's the regex expression for:

- Begins with a certain String? such as: begins with "/retour,merci"
- Ends with a certain String? such as: ends with "/blog-accueils.html"
- And Contains String? such as: contains "data/"

Comment: You just described it.

Comment: What you posted in answer should have been your question.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can proceed:

```
String patternStr = String.format(
    "^%s.*%s.*%s$",
    Pattern.quote("/retour,merci"),
    Pattern.quote("data/"),
    Pattern.quote("/blog-accueils.html")
);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
System.out.println(
    pattern.matcher("/retour,merci/foo/data/bar/blog-accueils.html").matches()
);
System.out.println(
    pattern.matcher("/retour,merci/foo/ata/bar/blog-accueils.html").matches()
);
System.out.println(
    pattern.matcher("/retour,merc/foo/data/bar/blog-accueils.html").matches()
);
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
false
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
^ #charracter for begin string
$ #charracter for ending string
[a-zA-Z]+ #regex for a word or you can use \w+ which mean words
```

so:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+$
```

If you want to match char like `/` add them like this `\/`

Read:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html

Test with:

https://regex101.com/